# A good editor/add-on for Sproutcore?

Tags: ide, editor, sproutcore

Is there a good editor/ide/add-on for sproutcore out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextMate has [a SproutCore bundle](http://github.com/sproutit/sproutcore-tmbundle) which is helpful - at the very least it runs JSLint on your .js files at save time, which stops a lot of basic syntax errors.

Comment: thanks, i tried it a while ago actually, but the main function i want is easily edit views. Or at least some add on that makes finding which view component to use when. And greenhouse is not working at all :(

Comment: Greenhouse had a small bug in it that should be fixed shortly (just getting the change integrated). Also, if you need more help, check out the irc channel #sproutcore or the mailing list sproutcore@googlegroups.com.

Answer (score 2):

I use Jetbrains WebStorm.

Good support for js, not SC specific, but somehow it does very good highlighting for SC as wel and syntax errors.

Also not heavyweight (read slow).

I like it very much, tried a couple of other before.

Intype is also nice, less syntax help and other features.
E-text editor is windows version of Textmate with less features, more mature then Intype.

Answer (score 0):

I use intellij.  you can ctrl-click into most methods, and the warnings that it provides are close to what jslint will give you.  You can also autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JetBrains Ruby Mine. It's pretty smart. Coding hinting has built in integration got GitHub and from what I can tell pretty light weight. Refactoring is pretty awesome too. One of the best I've seen.